# Could not find expected browser chrome locally

Tags: node.js, meteor, puppeteer

This Meteor code uses "puppeteer 8.0.0", "puppeteer-core 10.0.0", puppeteer-extra 3.1.18" and "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth 2.7.8", It gives this error:

> Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (884014).

Tried "npm install" for no avail. Reading up online, tried removing "puppeteer-core": "^10.0.0" from package.json dependencies for no avail.

Any help is much appriciated. Thanks

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const nameH = require('./NameH');

const puppeteerOptions = {
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--single-process', '--no-zygote', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
}

let browser;
let pageNameH;

const init = async () => {
    const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
    console.log('1')         //>>>>>>>>>>>> Prints 1
    puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
    console.log('2')         //>>>>>>>>>>>> Prints 2
    
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerOptions);
    console.log('3') //>>>>>>>>> DID NOT PRINT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    pageNameH = await browser.newPage();
    console.log('4')

    await pageNameH.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
    await pageNameH.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    await pageNameH.setRequestInterception(true);
    blockResources(pageNameH);
}

const blockResources = page => {
    page.on('request', (req) => {
    if (req.resourceType() == 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() == 'font' || req.resourceType() == 'image') {
        req.abort();
    }
    else {
        req.continue();
    }
    });
}


export const abc = async (nm, loc) => {
    try {
    console.log('name try')       //>>>>>>>>>>>> Prints "name try"
    if (!(browser && pageNameH))
        await init();
    //use "required" nameh here

    } catch (error) { // print the error <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    console.log("Could not launch Puppeteer or open a new page.\n" + error);
    if (browser && browser.close === 'function') await browser.close();
    }
}
```

```json
// included in package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "check": "^1.0.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^1.0.1",
    "nightmare": "^3.0.2",
    "pending-xhr-puppeteer": "^2.3.3",
    "puppeteer": "^8.0.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^10.0.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.1.18",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.11.11",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-block-resources": "^2.2.9",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.7.8"
},
```

Comment: What happens if you try to delete node_modules folder and npm install again?

Comment: The same problem even after deleting node_modules and npm install.

Comment: Could you also post your `package.json`? I mean just having a puppeteer in there should do it, so we'd better have a look at it.

Comment: updated the post with pacakge.json

Comment: Had same problem, deleting node_modules and npm install worked for me

Comment: @davilj, I tried that for no avail,

Answer (score 99):

may be you can try this, it works for me on linux(centOS), puppeteer(10.2.0).

```bash
cd ./node_modules/puppeteer
npm run install
```

If that fails, you can also try running:

```bash
cd ./node_modules/puppeteer
npm install
```

This will download the chromium to ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium

Comment: FYI, this also worked as a charm on AWS instance running CentOS, thanks a lot

Comment: puppeteer@19.2.2: It is `npm run postinstall` now. or `yarn run postinstall` what every you use.

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 as well.

Comment: This works. why did that chromium thing disappear? It was working before.

Comment: Worked on MacOS Ventura, thanks a lot.

Comment: Worked perfectly on WSL2

Answer (score 22):

Fixed it by running this command to install chromium manually.

```
node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

Comment: I just had to run it, now it's a .mjs file instead of a .js, but it works all the same!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I checked my env variables, and even though PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD was set to false, it was still not working. After I removed the variable (unset PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD for mac), it worked.

related dependancies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.0.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^10.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^10.0.0",
  }
```

Launching Chromium:

```
    import chromium from "chrome-aws-lambda";

    const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
    });
```

Comment: Why is "puppeteer-core" a dependency even though you don't use it in the code? Specifically `chromium.puppeteer.launch()` instead of `puppeteer.launch()`

Comment: I tried these exact dependency versions and got but got `WARNING: crash_report_exception_handler.cc(240)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)`

Answer (score 6):

if you are testing locally, make sure you have puppeteer installed as dev dependencies. specifically

```
npm install puppeteer --save-dev
```

https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/wiki/HOWTO:-Local-Development#workaround

this approach allows us to rely on puppeteer for local development and puppeteer-core for production deployments.

Comment: I copy pasted the npm install instruction in that README but got an error: `Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer puppeteer-core@"^10.1.0" from chrome-aws-lambda@10.1.0`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to specify as the `executablePath` Puppeteer launch option the fullpath to the local chromium used by Puppeteer.

Something like this:

```
const launchOptions = {
  // other options (headless, args, etc)
  executablePath: '/home/jack/repos/my-repo/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome'
}
```

As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137427/3036129), it seems that also referencing a chromium local binary would work, but I think it's a worse solution, since Puppeteer is [guaranteed to work only with the local bundled version of Chromium](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/#q-why-doesnt-puppeteer-vxxx-work-with-chromium-vyyy).

Comment: This answer is so underrated. In my case, I don't want full puppeteer. Just puppeteer-core is ok, but it just couldn't find the browser on my ubuntu 18. I just needed to tell it where it is then it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing my answer in, in hopes that it helps someone not waste their entire evening like I did.

I was writing a Typescript server that used Puppeteer, and I'm using [ESBuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) to transpile from TS to JS. In the build step, esbuild was trying to bundle everything into one file, but I had to instruct it to preserve the Puppeteer import from node_modules.

I did this by marking `puppeteer` as external. [See docs here](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#external).

Since `npm i` downloads a compatible version of chromium to the node_modules folder, once I preserved this import, it was able to find Chromium in the node_modules folder.

My build file looks like:

```js
require("esbuild").buildSync({
  entryPoints: ["src/index.ts"],
  outdir: "build",
  bundle: true,
  platform: "node",
  target: "node16",
  external: ["puppeteer"],
});
```

And I run it with `node prod-build.js`.

Now in my code, I can just call launch!
`const browser = await puppeteer.launch()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'm testing rather a not popular setup - Angular Universal where Express serves both for REST API and for SSR. Adding the "puppeteer" to _externals_ of a custom webpack config for server app solved the problem!

Comment: This approach pointed me in the right direction. There's another question (and answer) that highlights the exact steps when using angular univeral. This solved the issue for me, so I'm also linking it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622351/the-angular-universal-ssr-cannot-integrate-with-the-external-libraries-like-pu

Answer (score 0):

I used the installed version on my pc (maybe not what you're looking for)

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false,  executablePath: 
           'C:/Program Files/.../chrome.exe' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install some dependencies depending on your OS. Check Puppeteer's [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md) page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error too and I noticed that I started getting such an error after updating my node from my Dockerfile to version ^16 (my puppeteer is in a container). How did I solve it? I downgraded my node from Dockerfile to version 12.
Hope this resolves it...

OBS: I use Ubuntu 21.04 in machine.

EDIT ------

In newest versions of node, you need to go in ./node_modules/puppeteer and run command   npm install, then the correct packages will be installed.
I'm using that solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using puppeteer in AWS SAM and you don't have `puppeteer` in dependencies, you can install the same in `puppeteer-core` using

```
   node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

For this setup to work you will have to add `chrome-aws-lambda` in the `devDependencies`.

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0"
     }
```

Also before you take it to production don't forget to add the layer in your `template.yaml` file:

```
Layers:
     - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:764866452798:layer:chrome-aws-lambda:25'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I ran npm install although I shouldn't have. Just deleted the node_modules folder and then ran again - now worked

Answer (score 0):

`puppeteer-extra` does not include `chromium`.
(chromium is a headless version of chrome browser)

you need to install `puppeteer` package

> npm install puppeteer

or just simple add `executablePath` if you don't want to install chromium (I assume you have Chrome browser in your system

```
const CHROME_EXECUTALBE_PATH = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            executablePath: CHROME_EXECUTALBE_PATH,
            headless: true
        });
```

to get the path, open your browse, type `chrome://version/`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Volta](https://volta.sh/) and when I installed Puppeteer, I had accidentally used Node v10.16.0 with npm 6.9.0 and it apparently couldn't install Chromium.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. `volta pin node@18.17.0`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm install puppeteer`

Now I can see Chromium in `~/.cache/puppeteer/` and I can run Puppeteer in my project.

Apparently, older Node versions interfere with the install script.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and run

```bash
npm install
```