# The Angular Universal (SSR) cannot integrate with the external libraries like puppeteer, bulljs

Tags: angularjs, puppeteer, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, bull

This is just for describing the issue and sharing my solution, I got stuck a lot of time on it.

This issue happened after I upgraded the Angular 10 -> 11 and changed the builder from `udk:udk-runner` to `@angular-devkit`

The issue I was facing is when I set the field `bundleDependencies` in angular.json to `true` . The Puppeteer cannot start with the error cannot launch the browser

[image]

Then I found it also happened on the other external libraries I'm using at the Server side like `BullJS` `Bull-Board` `Puppeteer-Cluster` with the below error

[image]

**Github source for demo the issue**: https://github.com/phattranky/angular-ssr-error-with-pupepteer

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple you just need to add `externalDependencies` below the field `bundleDependencies`, which are the libraries we are using.

```
"externalDependencies": ["puppeteer", "puppeteer-cluster", "bull", "bull-board"]
```

Sample:

[image]

What is the `externalDependencies` ?

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/server/schema.json

[image]

If you have the better solution and any feedbacks, please share for me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for this! On the off chance someone finds this due to the same problem I had: "Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: _waitForPredicatePageFunction is not defined" brought me here. Adding comment, so it may show up in a search. 
I had found a workaround for the initial problem (Chrome not starting), by passing the executablePath like so: puppeteer.launch({executablePath: /.../node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-v3r510n/chrome-linux/chrome"});
This makes some of puppeteer work but leads to follow-up issues. Your solution is much better.