# Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - /home/pptruser/app/node_modules/jest-environment-puppeteer/setup.js

Tags: node.js, docker, jestjs, puppeteer, chromium

When running from local, its getting passed. Below error is thrown when run from docker locally. I am in the process of setting up my code for my puppeteer test.

I also included here below package.json, jest-puppeteer.config, jest.config files. Here I haven't included my tests files.

shall you please someone help ? Thanks.

```
Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - /home/pptruser/app/node_modules/jest-environment-puppeteer/setup.js, reason: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (1022525).
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:23)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async setup (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/jest-environment-puppeteer/lib/global.js:37:16)
    at async /home/pptruser/app/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runGlobalHook.js:125:13
    at async waitForPromiseWithCleanup (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:209:5)
    at async runGlobalHook (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runGlobalHook.js:116:9)
    at async runJest (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:369:5)
    at async _run10000 (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
    at async runCLI (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
    at async Object.run (/home/pptruser/app/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:155:37)
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-puppeteer" 
  notifyMode: "always",
  maxWorkers: "50%",
  maxConcurrency: 150,
  maxWorkers: 1,
  bail: 1,
  collectCoverage: true,
  testRunner: "jest-jasmine2",
  timers: "fake",
  testTimeout: 9000000,
  watchman: false,
};
```

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-cli": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-jasmine2": "^27.2.3",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^6.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "puppeteer": "^14.1.2" 
}
```

jest-puppeteer.config:

```
module.exports = {
    launch: {
        headless: true,
        slowMo: 0,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ["--window-size=1920,1080",
        "--incognito",
        "--start-maximized",
        "--disable-extensions",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--no-first-run",
        "--no-zygote"],
        setDefaultNavigationTimeout: 8000000,
        setDefaultTimeout: 8000000,
    },
    browserContext: "default",
};
```

My docker file:

```
FROM docker-remote.artifactory.oci.oraclecorp.com/oraclelinux:7-slim
 COPY --from=odo-docker-signed-local.artifactory.oci.oraclecorp.com/odo/base-image-support:ol7x-1.6 / /
RUN yum-config-manager --add-repo https://artifactory.oci.oraclecorp.com/io-ol7-nodejs16-yum-local/ \
    --add-repo https://artifactory.oci.oraclecorp.com/io-ol7-oracle-instant-client-yum-local/ \

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    ORACLE_NPM=https://artifactory.oci.oraclecorp.com/api/npm/npm-remote/
RUN yum -y update \
    && yum -y install nodejs-16.14.2-1.0.1.el7.x86_64 chromium-102.0.5005.115-1.el7.x86_64 
    
RUN groupadd -r pptruser  \
    && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/app \   
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser
WORKDIR /home/pptruser/app
COPY --chown=pptruser:pptruser . .
CMD ["npm","run-script smoke"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way we solved this was to download Chromium https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ and unzip into a specific folder:    `.\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium\win64-722234`

Some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69191210/8340915) include specifying the path to your chromium like so:

```
const launchOptions = {
    // other options (headless, args, etc)
    executablePath: '/home/jack/repos/my-repo/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome'
}
```