# deno puppeteer 'chrome not found' trying to import npm dependency

Tags: typescript, npm, puppeteer, deno

I'm trying to use [`node-html-to-image`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-to-image) in deno:

```
import nodeHtmlToImage from "npm:node-html-to-image";

nodeHtmlToImage({
  output: './image.png',
  html: '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>'
})
  .then(() => console.log('The image was created successfully!'))
```

`deno run --allow-env --allow-read --allow-write that-file.ts` causes this error:

```
error: Uncaught Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (982053).
    at Cluster.<anonymous> (file:///Users/theonlygusti/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-cluster/0.23.0/dist/Cluster.js:119:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (file:///Users/theonlygusti/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-cluster/0.23.0/dist/Cluster.js:6:65)
```

How can I use the `node-html-to-image` npm package from Deno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is answered in [Could not find expected browser chrome locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051648/could-not-find-expected-browser-chrome-locally).

The Deno-specific part is, that the NPM installation directory is different from the usual Node installations.

When you use the [npm specifier](https://deno.land/manual@v1.29.2/node/npm_specifiers) in Deno, e.g. `import nodeHtmlToImage from "npm:node-html-to-image";`, the Node packages will be installed in a part of the deno caches directory:

- Windows: `<user directory>/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/`
- macOS: `~/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org`
- Linux: `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org`  or `$HOME/.cache/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org`

and specifically for Puppeteer:
`deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer/13.7.0`

In the error message it's mentioned to

> Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (982053)

That means you should run `npm install` in the above Puppeteer's directory, which contains a file named install.js.

This will install the correct revision of the chromium package into the Puppeteer's directory under `.local-chromium`.

The bad news is (at least under Windows), that you'll probably get the next error, which is

> Uncaught Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Windows only supports ctrl-c (SIGINT) and ctrl-break (SIGBREAK).

Comment: Is there any way to fix the last error?